# JTAppleCalendar - custom number of columns

Tags: ios, calendar

I'm using JTAppleCalendar and wanted to make layout with only 1 column, vertical scroll.

I've seen NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7 that strictly influences number of columns, but changing it will probably cause some bugs and is not elegant.

Vertical scrolling made by changing:

```
  self.calendarView.direction =  .Vertical
```

Is it possible to easily change number of columns?

Comment: You know, asking this question on my gihub repository would get you a much faster response. That said, you cannot change the number of days in a week. I have coded it as 7. Changing this would mess up a lot of other calculations. I can look into an enhancement where you can make the columns flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!